# XML layout declaration probing in android

Tags: android, onclick, android-custom-view

I have a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pronounce"
                     style="@style/pronounce"
                     android:onClick="pronounce_onClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And a `PronounceView` which extends `LinearLayout` and inflates the above layout. `PronunceView` is in package `com.company.sample.text`.

The inflation:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.pronouncelayout, this);
```

and `pronounce_onClick`

```
    public void pronounce_onClick(View v) {
        pronounce();
    }
```

I've learned that the the method `pronounce_onClick` in `PronounceView` won't be called by `android:onClick` declaration in XML layout bur rather it will work by `setOnClickListener` in `PronounceView`.

Also, I've learned that `android:onClick` declaration can fire any appropriate method that are in the package of `PronounceView` (`com.company.sample.text`) but not out of that (as an example: `com.company.sample.sound`).

Did I understand it correctly? And anyone can tell me the reason of such a probing mechanism or somehow limitation?

Comment: you mean to say your pronounce_onClick method is not being called on button click. can you please add the code for it and for how you are declaring PronounceView

Comment: As I said, the pronounce_onClick does not fire if declared in xml layout but it works if defined by setOnClickListener via code

Comment: ok.  have used functions declared in xml layout. please add the code for how layout is inflated by pronounceview and the code for your pronounce_onClick method

Answer (score 1):

That's because `android:onClick` attribute tries to invoke the method on the view's context, not on the view itself nor on it's parent - check the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick).

In your case, you are better off setting `OnClickListener` for ImageButton in your code, in `PronounceView` constructor for example. It is faster as well, since it does not rely on reflection for invoking the method.